# how to send view menu path as parameter

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

```
 I define a menu in drupal7 that look something like:
       school
       --people
       ----teachers
       ----pupils
```

I create:

1. Content type for people.
2. Menu with the above titles.

When I add person to people’s content, I choose if he belong to 
'teachers' or 'pupils' in the menu.

Now I need that pressing on the menu will give me a list of all that kind of people. 
For example, pressing on ‘school->people->teachers’ will give me the list of all 
the teachers,  one line for each teacher.

So I thing to build a view that get the menu/sub menu as parameter and give me the 
appropriate output.

But **I don’t know** how:

1. Send to a view the menu / sub menu as parameters. (How to send parameters to a view)
2. How to filter the view by this parameter and create the specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 views pages (teacher and pupils)

Where you will show list of all the teachers or pupils

In menu ----teachers add path on views page teachers.

In menu ----pupils add path on views page pupils.

After click on menu you will redirect to the desired page

Update Watch Duplicate Copy Move